# Find the first non-missing value in a set of variables for each unique person and then change all NAs to 0 after that point

Tags: r

I have a wide dataset with 1 row per person. Each person has a set of 12 variables representing a visit for each month of the year. If a person did not have a visit for a month, it currently says NA. If a person had multiple visits within a month, the number is the number of visits. For example, a patient was seen for the first time in February, and they had 2 visits. The January column is NA because they were not seen then and the February column is 2 because they had 2 visits in that month. The rest of the months for that person would be filled in accordingly if they had visits or not.

My goal is to find the first non-missing value and then any months after their first visit with no visits needs to be changed to 0. I still want to keep months before their first visit as NA. I have 'have' and 'want' data sets provided.

I have made attempts at loops, if statements, and functions, but am not having any success. Does anybody have experience with this type of code?

HAVE:

```
|ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | Jul |
|:--|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:----:|:---:|
| 1 |  NA |  1  |  1  | 2   | NA  | NA   | NA  |
| 2 |  NA | NA  | NA  | 1   | NA  |  NA  |  NA |
| 3 |  1  | NA  | 1   | 3   | 1   | NA   | NA  |  
| 4 |  NA | NA  | NA  | NA  | NA  | 1    | 1   |
```

WANT:

```
|ID | Jan | Feb | Mar | Apr | May | June | Jul |
|:--|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:---:|:----:|:---:|
| 1 |  NA |  1  |  1  | 2   |  0  | 0    | 0   |
| 2 |  NA | NA  | NA  | 1   | 0  |  0  |  0 |
| 3 |  1  | 0  | 1   | 3   | 1   | 0   | 0  |  
| 4 |  NA | NA  | NA  | NA  | NA  | 1    | 1   |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use a vectorized option with `max.col` to find the column index of the first non-NA element excluding the first column for each row.  Then, create a logical matrix by checking whether this `rep`licated index is less than the `col`um index and (`&`) if the values are `NA` to return a logical `matrix` which we use to subset the data and assign (`<-`) to 0

```
df1[-1][col(df1[-1]) > max.col(!is.na(df1[-1]), 'first')[
         row(df1[-1])] & is.na(df1[-1])] <- 0
```

-output

```
> df1
  ID Jan Feb Mar Apr May June Jul
1  1  NA   1   1   2   0    0   0
2  2  NA  NA  NA   1   0    0   0
3  3   1   0   1   3   1    0   0
4  4  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA    1   1
```

---

Or using `apply`

```
df1[] <-  t(apply(df1[-1], 1, FUN = function(x) 
    replace(x, seq_along(x) > which(!is.na(x))[1] & is.na(x), 0)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Jan = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), Feb = c(1L, 
NA, NA, NA), Mar = c(1L, NA, 1L, NA), Apr = c(2L, 1L, 3L, NA), 
    May = c(NA, NA, 1L, NA), June = c(NA, NA, NA, 1L), Jul = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
))
```

Comment: Great, thank you so much! That looks like it worked. I will try the apply version too just for learning purposes. I appreciate the help!

Comment: is there a way to easily manipulate this code to find the first non-NA month for each person again and then add 2 to that and then see if that value (month + 2) equals a value in another column?

Comment: @Sophia can you post as a new question. thanks

Comment: Yes, i will do that. thank you!

Comment: @Sophia thanks, it will be easier to understand the expected output in a different post

Comment: Totally understandable, I posted it in another question. I do not think it should actually be hard at all, I just can't fine tune it

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` solution using pivoting, grouping and filling:

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(-ID) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(temp = 1 * !cumall(is.na(value))) %>%
  fill(temp) %>% 
  mutate(value = ifelse(temp == 1 & is.na(value), 0, value))  %>% 
  pivot_wider(-temp, names_from = name, values_from = value)
```